# Round to IEEE 754 precision but keep binary format

Tags: c, algorithm, formula, ieee-754, fixed-point

If I convert the decimal number 3120.0005 to float (32-bit) representation, the number gets rounded down to 3120.00048828125.

Assuming we're using a fixed point number with a scale of 10^12 then 1000000000000 = 1.0 and 3120000500000000 = 3120.0005.

What would the formula/algorithm be to round down to the nearest IEEE 754 precision to get 3120000488281250?
I would also need a way to get the result of rounding up (3120000732421875).

Comment: I guess the simplest approach is to convert to float and then back to your format.

Comment: How are you storing the fixed point number?

Comment: @user3386109 with a scale of 10^12, so 3120.0005 = 3120000500000000

Comment: Find the largest power of two not greater than *x*. Let *p* be that divided by 2^23. Find the multiple of *p* closest to *x*. That is the result.

Comment: `"rounding up (3120000732421875)"` is a bit misleading. In order to arrive a `3120000732421875` as the next values above `3120000500000000` with a `float` scaled by `1e12`. You are not so much finding the next representable floating point value as you are finding the next higher `unsigned` equivalent 32-bits. A simple `union` between `float` and `unsigned` with the `float` initialized to `x / 1.0e12` and then adding `1` to the unsigned value will give `3120000732421875` as then new float value multiplied by `1e12`.

Comment: Some results are not representable in your format. For example, for the representable input 1.0000001, the nearest IEEE-754 32-bit binary value is 1.00000011920928955078125, but that is not representable in your format. What result do you want then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you divide by the decimal scaling factor, you'll find your nearest representable float.  For rounding the other direction, `std::nextafter` can be used:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long long scale_to_fixed(float f)
{
    float intf = truncf(f);
    long long result = 1000000000000LL;
    result *= (long long)intf;
    result += round((f - intf) * 1.0e12);
    return result;
}

/* not needed, always good enough to use (float)(n / 1.0e12) */
float scale_from_fixed(long long n)
{
    float result = (n % 1000000000000LL) / 1.0e12;
    result += n / 1000000000000LL;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    long long x = 3120000500000000;
    float x_reduced = scale_from_fixed(x);
    long long y1 = scale_to_fixed(x_reduced);
    long long yfloor = y1, yceil = y1;
    if (y1 < x) {
        yceil = scale_to_fixed(nextafterf(x_reduced, FLT_MAX));
    }
    else if (y1 > x) {
        yfloor = scale_to_fixed(nextafterf(x_reduced, -FLT_MAX));
    }

    printf("%lld\n%lld\n%lld\n", yfloor, x, yceil);
}
```

Results:

> 3120000488281250
>
> 3120000500000000
>
> 3120000732421875

Comment: @user3386109: Results are the same, code changes were to make it compatible with C instead of using C++ names for the same functions.

Comment: @user3386109: Sorry, I had made that change (from `roundf` to `round`) when I tested the C++ -> C port, but forgot to here.

Comment: This code does not handle the case where the input is exactly representable, for which the “round down” and “round up” cases should both produce the input value, unchanged. Additionally, `x / 1.0e12` is subject to rounding errors. And the question’s sample, 3120000500000000, is close to the limit of representable consecutive integers in the common `double` format—values exceeding 9007199254740992 may have rounding errors when the `long long` is converted to `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Does that fix it?

Comment: Possibly `scale_to_fixed` is fine for the places it is used. But I was actually concerned with `float x_reduced = x / 1.0e12;`. Before the division, `x` is converted to `double`. That could involve a rounding error. Then the division can introduce another rounding error. I have not investigated whether there are any cases where that leads to an error in the final result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Both of those errors are eclipsed by the rounding which occurs when the result is converted from `double` to `float`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: But just in case it would cause rounding into a different bucket, here's a version which eliminates the error at the conversion to `double`.

Comment: A tiny change can move a value from one side of a rounding point to another—rounding errors in the calculation of a `double` can change what happens when the `double` is rounded to a `float`. In other words, the difference between a `double` that rounds to a `float` `x0` and a `double` that rounds to a `float` x1 may be as small as 1 ULP in the `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Still, that would only have affected the round-to-nearest result.  You'd get the floor instead of the ceiling, or vice-versa, and only if the input value was almost exactly halfway between.  And then the logic for getting both floor and ceiling would still have worked.

Comment: Okay, I will look at it more later.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle the values as `float` scaled by `1e12` and compute the next larger power of two, e.g. `"rounding up (3120000732421875)"`, the key is understanding that you are looking for the next larger power of two from the 32-bit representation of `x / 1.0e12`. While you can mathematically arrive at this value, a `union` between `float` and `unsigned` (or `uint32_t`) provides a direct way to interpret the stored 32-bit value for the floating-point number as an unsigned value.<sup>**1**</sup>

A simple example utilizing a the union `prev` to hold the reduced value of `x` and a separate instance `next` holding the unsigned value (`+1`) can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main (void) {

    uint64_t x = 3120000500000000;
    union {                         /* union between float and uint32_t */
        float f;
        uint32_t u;
    } prev = { .f = x / 1.0e12 },   /* x reduced to float, pwr of 2 as .u */
      next = { .u = prev.u + 1u };  /* 2nd union, increment pwr of 2 by 1 */

    printf ("prev : %" PRIu64 "\n   x : %" PRIu64 "\nnext : %" PRIu64 "\n", 
            (uint64_t)(prev.f * 1e12), x, (uint64_t)(next.f * 1e12));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pwr2_prev_next
prev : 3120000488281250
   x : 3120000500000000
next : 3120000732421875
```

**Footnotes:**

**1.** As an alternative, you can use a *pointer to* `char` to hold the address of the floating point type and interpret the 4-byte value stored at that location as `unsigned` without running afoul of [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) (the *"Strict Aliasing Rule"*), but the use of a `union` is preferred.

Comment: "increment pwr of 2 by 1" literally means you are changing the exponent, but actually you're incrementing the mantissa.

Comment: @ David This answer has an issue that Ben's code attempts to avoid. When the computation `x / 1.0e12` rounds up, then both `prev` and `next` are larger than `x`. This can be demonstrated by starting with the value 3120000700000000. In addition, there's the question of whether `next` should be greater than `prev` in the case where `x / 1.0e12` has an exact representation as a `float`. This can be demonstrated with the value 3120500000000000. Admittedly, that's more of a question for the OP.

Comment: Yes, this was apparent and why I included the quoted `"rounding up (3120000732421875)"` in the question explaining that to obtain that answer, you were not finding the next possible floating-point representation, but instead were manipulating the bits of the equivalent unsigned value. I get Ben's answer through proper math described by Eric in the comments under the question, but to get the `"rounding up (3120000732421875)"` value takes manipulating the 32-bit value (such as the combination `round(nextafterf(...))` does.